# How to fix the error Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20200818_123041.jpg' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-permissions, targetsdkversion

I'm trying to allow a user to pick an image from their photo gallery on their device.

My previous code worked fine, but now that I have to update the targetSdkVersion from 28 to 29, its not working any more.

I've tried adding

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

But still not working. Also tried using the `permission_handler` flutter package.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Any errors or excceptions? Please tell what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem in the end. I needed to set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in android manifest, and change the `compileSdkVersion` to 29 aswell (it was still on 28, even though I'd changed the `targetSdkVersion`to 29) - you must need to change both in the app level build.gradle.

Hope this helps someone, so glad I fixed my issue!

Comment: This is a temporary solution

Answer (score 1):

> Need to give permission on your android manifest file.
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> ```
>
> [And also use this for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)
>
> Follow all steps as per above link.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `permission_handler` and you writed:
`if (!status.isGranted) { await Permission.storage.request(); }`

The application asks for permission?

You can write `print` before `if` statement, in conditions and after `if` statement